# Android room how to return a flow of Map where the map value can be a pair or an object?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room

I have a table like this:

```
data class ChapterDetails(
   val id: Int,
   var correctAnswersCount: Int,
   var totalQuestionsCount: Int,
   // ... ... ...
)
```

I would like to return a Flow<Map<Int, Pair<Int, Int>> > from the room dao. I saw this [stackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72990697/9053942), and this [mapInfo doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/MapInfo) but they return only 2 comumns. I need a map where the key is Id, and value is a pair of <correctAnswersCount, totalQuestionsCount>. What is the room way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably not exactly what you want, but an alternative to writing complex SQL query can be to transform the flow of list of `ChapterDetails` which can be returned by the DAO easily.

```kotlin
interface ChapterDetailsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM ChapterDetails")
    fun getChapterDetails(): Flow<List<ChapterDetails>>
}

val chapterDetailsMapFlow: Flow<Map<Int, Pair<Int, Int>>> =  
    dao.getChapterDetails().map { list ->
        list.associate { it.id to (it. correctAnswersCount to it. totalQuestionsCount) }
    }
```

If you are worried that fetching all the columns when you only need three will impact performance, I guess you will have to create a new data class consisting only those particular columns, but even then you will have to convert the list to map yourself as above.

```kotlin
data class ChapterDetailsCounts(
   val id: Int,
   var correctAnswersCount: Int,
   var totalQuestionsCount: Int
)

interface ChapterDetailsDao {
    @Query("SELECT id, correctAnswersCount, totalQuestionsCount FROM ChapterDetails")
    fun getChapterDetails(): Flow<List<ChapterDetailsCounts>>
}
```

Comment: Thanks. For now, I am doing something similar using stream.

Answer (score 1):

You could something like:-

A) Have a suitable POJO e.g. :-

```
data class ChapterDetailsCount(
    val chapterDetailsCount: Map<Int,Pair<Int,Int>>
)
```

B) Have a base query that gets the respective ChapterDetails list. e.g.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM ChapterDetails")
fun getChapterDetails(): List<ChapterDetails>
```

C) Have a function (in the `@Dao` annotated interface) **with a body**, that uses the base query to get the ChapterDetails list but then returns the list of the POJO e.g.

```
fun getChapterDetailsCountList(): List<ChapterDetailsCount> {
    val rv: ArrayList<ChapterDetailsCount> = arrayListOf()
    for (cd in getChapterDetails()) {
        rv.add(ChapterDetailsCount(mapOf(cd.id to Pair(first = cd.correctAnswersCount, second = cd.totalQuestionsCount))))
    }
    return rv.toList()
}
```

- Note I haven't used Flow because I don't do stuff with Flow

The following demonstrates:-

```
    db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
    dao = db.getChapterDetailsDao()

    val t1 = dao.getChapterDetailsCountList()
    dao.insert(ChapterDetails(100,5,10))
    val t2 = dao.getChapterDetailsCountList()
```

- with a breakpoint after the last line and :-

[image]

- i.e.

  - first is empty as expected (now rows exist at that point)
  - second has the expected data from the first row
- You just need to adapt it to use Flow