# Room Library - relationship between tables having auto generated keys

Tags: android, android-room

The examples I came across were forming relations without primary key, my database schema is as follow.

I have primary key in both tables, and I'm attempting to create a DAO method that will join both user and department tables to display a record.

**Question**, how to create a DAO method to access the record joined by the department information. I prefer to do **without creating more data classes if possible**. for instance using `Map<User, Department>`. If there's none then I will accept other solutions.

**User Table**

```
+----+----------+----------+---------------+
| id | username |   name   | department_id |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+
|  1 | johndoe  | John Doe |             3 |
|  2 | janedoe  | Jane Doe |             4 |
+----+----------+----------+---------------+
```

**User data class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true) var id: Long,
    var username: String,
    var name: String,
    var department_id: Long)
```

**Department Table**

```
+----+----------------+
| id |      name      |
+----+----------------+
|  1 | Sales          |
|  2 | Account        |
|  3 | Human Resource |
|  4 | Marketing      |
+----+----------------+
```

**Department data class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "department")
data class Department(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long,
    var name: String)
```

---

**My attempt at DAO**

```
@Dao
interface UserDAO {

    @Query("SELECT user.*, department.name AS 'department_name' FROM user " +
            "INNER JOIN department ON user.department_id = department.id " +
            "WHERE user.id = :id")
    fun findById(id: Long): Map<User, Department>
}
```

---

**Edit**

Will it work if Department is composed inside User? If that's the case then how the query inside DAO would look like?

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true) var id: Long,
    var username: String,
    var name: String,
    @Embedded var department: Department)

data class Department(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long,
    var name: String? = null): Parcelable
```

**DAO attempt**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user " +
    "INNER JOIN department d ON department.id = d.id " +
    "WHERE id = :id")
fun findById(id: Long): Map<User, Department>
```

Comment: Did you forget `FROM user`?

Comment: Thanks, added the missing info, any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works as it is **BUT** due to ambiguous column names (id and name) values are not as expected.

Here's the result (noting that User id's are 500 and 501 instead of 1 and 2 to better highlight the issue) when debugging, with a breakpoint at a suitable place and when using:-

```
findById(500)
```

then the debugger shows :-

[image]

That is that although John's department id is 3, it is instead 500 in the **Department** itself, likewise the name of the department is ***John Doe*** not the expected ***Human Resource**.

This is because Room doesn't know which id is for what and likewise name.

The fix is to use unique column names. e.g. with:-

```
@Entity(tableName = "department")
data class Department(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "dept_id")
    var id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "dept_name")
    var name: String
 )
```

- i.e. the columns in the table, but not in the Department have been changed. You could just change the name of the fields to be unique names.

Obviously if the column names are changed then the SQL has to be changed accordingly, so :-

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user " +
        "INNER JOIN department ON department_Id = dept_id " +
        "WHERE id = :id")
fun findById(id: Long): Map<User, Department>
```

- as the column names now have no ambiguities then there is no need to use table names to differentiate (you still can. Without the table banes the SQL can be more concise.

Now Debug shows:-

[image]

**Additional re Edit**

> Will it work if Department is composed inside User?

If you use `@Embedded` within an `@Entity` annotated class that is included in the `entities` parameter of the `@Database` annotated class then the resultant table has columns as per the embedded class.

If the embedded class was previously a table then in respect of the relationship that doesn't exist and that previous table may well be defunct.

There is an issue with the embedded Department in that you will have 2 columns named **id**

From a database perspective, if what was a 1 to many relationship then the same data (e.g. Human Resource) will be repeated and is contrary to normalisation.

In regard to the query

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user " +
    "INNER JOIN department d ON department.id = d.id " +
    "WHERE id = :id")
fun findById(id: Long): Map<User, Department>
```

Then this will not work as there will be no department table (as according to your code the Department class is not annotated with `@Entity`).

Comment: Thanks @MikeT, slight deviation, is there a solution if `User` is composed of `Department`, see my Edit section please.

Comment: @Source answer has been edited accordingly (in short not a recommended approach)

Comment: please review my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Room supports this since version `2.4` as described in the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#multimap). Similar issue to yours appear to be solved also in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72990697/5473567

In your concrete example you are forgetting, that the relation is 1:N, therefore your return type in the DAO function should look like this `Map<User, List<Department>>`.

Also the `department.name AS 'department_name'` in your SELECT is wrong. The field `name` in the `data class Department` is called **name**, therefore also in Database table **department** this field will be called **name**. If you would like to change its name to the `department_name` as you use in your SELECT, you have to use annotation `@ColumnInfo` as described in [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#anatomy). The data class will then look like this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "department")
data class Department(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "department_name") var name: String
)
```

Last tip, if you are pulling full data from the database, there is enough to use `SELECT * FROM...`, Room will resolve it for you.

Finally the whole DAO interface may look like this:

```
@Dao
interface UserDAO {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM user " +
        "INNER JOIN department ON user.department_id = department.id " +
        "WHERE user.id = :id")
    fun findById(id: Long): Map<User, Department>
}
```

Comment: Thanks @David, slight deviation, is it possible to have if `User` is composed of `Department`, is there a DAO solution possible?

Comment: If you mean, that User object has a field of type of Department, then, yes, it is possible with @Embedded annotation. Please check the documentation here:  https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#nested-objects Also, to not disturb your entity classes directly, you may want to use something what is called "Intermediate data class" described here: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships#data-class

Comment: Sure David. The problem is I can't wrap my head around DAO query in this case (Department composed inside User), or will the same query work?

Comment: This starts to deviate a lot from the original question. I will try to respond in here, but if you will not figure it out, it is better to create a new thread. Create new data class UserWithDepartment with annotated fields @Embedded user: User and another field List<Department> annotaded with @Relation(parentColumn = "id", entityColumn = "department_id"). Method of DAO class will now have UserWithDepartment return type and your SQL will be "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user.id =: id". On the background Room will run two queries to be able to return you the Intermediate object UserWithDepartment.

Comment: okay, I'll attempt it, and if it fails, I'll link another question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Based on the answers, here's my solution without using additional data classes while also keeping the column names intact, for instance using `id` column in each table without any prefix (preferable). I had to use `user.id` in the `WHERE` clause to avoid ambiguity

**User**

```
@Entity(tableName = "user")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey (autoGenerate = true) 
    var id: Long,
    var username: String,
    var name: String,
    var department_id: Long)
```

**Department**

```
@Entity(tableName = "department")
data class Department(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Long,
    var name: String)
```

**DAO Query**

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user " +
        "INNER JOIN department ON user.department_id = department.id " + // fixed from user.id = department.id
        "WHERE user.id = :id")
fun find(id: Long): Map<User, Department>
```

Comment: suggest you change `SELECT *` to `SELECT user.*` else there will be 2 **id** columns selected per output row and I believe one id (user) will be incorrect (instead it will be the department id). Hard to see when 2 users and 2 invoices with generated id's as ids will only be 1 and 2.

Comment: Read that it's fixed in `2.5.0` which I'm using but not sure how, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201306012

Comment: my bad, my join was wrong, changed `user.id = department.id` to `user.department_id = department.id`, please check.